# Can't import play.api.test._ into scala REPL

Tags: scala, playframework

I have entered the REPL through SBT 'above' my Play project. All the objects and classes are accessible through the REPL with the excepetion of

```
import play.api.test._
```

This tells me the "object test is not a member of package play.api" which is clearly not the case. I am using IntelliJ IDEA and have a sneaky feeling this might be to do with the 'test' scope, but other than that intuition I am stuck to unravel this mystery further.

Grateful for any help here. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Start the console with:

```
play test:console
```

See the section "Selecting the configuration" in the [SBT docs](http://www.scala-sbt.org/release/docs/Detailed-Topics/Inspecting-Settings.html) (which also apply to any play-specific commands).